Cyclic cataclysmic events 12 000 years apart
I have read in several places that there is evidence in the geologic record (rocks and ice cores) of cataclysmic events that regularly occur 12 ka apart.
There is a term I only barely understand called “punctuated aggradational* cycles” where there is a recurring thin layer indicating a radical but short lived event, and 12 ka worth of regular events/normal living, followed by the next short lived radical event right on time — rinse and repeat.
So is there actually evidence of recurring cyclical cataclysmic events occurring regularly in the geologic record or not?
Asking as a layman and looking for answers “even I can understand”.
I started here:  https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1029/PA001i004p00417 And another: https://journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/628978?journalCode=jg
More:  https://www.google.com/search?q=punctuated+aggradational+cycles
*edit: typo

Could you provide links to a couple places that make this claim?

Maybe a different phrase? "Punctuated aggregation cycles" doesn't bring up anything in Google. The closest thing is some "doom is coming" YouTube video that reinterprets the regional Younger Dryas black mats from ~12ka years ago as being global and from some non-organic source and assumes the black mat layers repeated as regular intervals.

Here's one example:  https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1029/PA001i004p00417
And another:   https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/628978?journalCode=jg
I misspelled my question originally.  It's punctuated aggradational cycles.     I'm a little surprised nobody caught that -- I guess it really is a one-off weird term.
https://www.google.com/search?q=punctuated+aggradational+cycles
